# If $f$ is entire and $f(z)\leq e^{a|z|^b}$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$ then $ \frac{|f^{(n)}(0)|}{n!} \leq \left( \frac{abe}{n} \right)^{n/b} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function satisfying $f(z)\leq e^{a|z|^b}$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$. How can I show that $$ \frac{|f^{(n)}(0)|}{n!} \leq \left( \frac{abe}{n} \right)^{n/b}  $$
holds? (Here, $a, b$ are fixed positive constants.) I tried to use the Cauchy estimate: given $r>0$, we have $$ f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}~dz$$
and therefore $$ |f^{(n)}(0)|\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{e^{ar^b}}{r^{n+1}} \cdot 2\pi r = \frac{n! e^{ar^b}}{r^n} .$$

But I have no idea to get the desired conclusion. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a,b >0$ as otherwise the function is constant. Pick $r$ s.t. $r^b=\frac{n}{ab}$ Then $r^n=(\frac{n}{ab})^{\frac{n}{b}}$ hence you are done by substituting in the relation you got above.

Comment: nice! +1, maybe im missing something easy but why would $f$ be constant if $a,b \le 0$ ?

Comment: @ infinity Entire bounded at infinity

Comment: Right! forgot that.